# How to create new File txt by using Adobe Air

Tags: file, file-io, air, new-operator

I want to ask how to create new file with adobe air so i can write it.....
And how to put it in our current project?

I have seen so many resource, but they used existed file that created manually and only update it content...

Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

everything is explained (with sample code) in the documentation:

1. [flash.filesystem.FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html)
2. [flash.filesystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)
3. [Reading and writing files (Adobe AIR 1.0 and later)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc2.html)

Comment: ok thankyou...I have one question again.. how to get path of our project?

Comment: File.applicationDirectory — the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)

Answer (score 0):

```
private var fileReferenceSave:FileReference= new FileReference();
private function onSaveText():void
{
    fileReference.save(myText.text,"myText.txt");
}
```