# How to create NEW txt file using Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file, adobe

How to create a REALY NEW text file (.txt) using AS3 adobe AIR. Most articles are writing to EXISTING text file (text file already exist).

like this one:
[How to create new File txt by using Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104219/how-to-create-new-file-txt-by-using-adobe-air)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
//create a reference to the file in the applicationStorage Directory 
//(for more directories, look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html
var fileToCreate:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
fileToCreate          = fileToCreate.resolvePath("myfile.txt");

//create a filestream to write to the file
//the write and/or creating the file is done with the FileMode in the open() function
//look at the table that describes what FileMode does what here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileMode.html
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(fileToCreate, FileMode.WRITE);

//write some string to the file
fileStream.writeUTF('this is a string to write to the file');

//finally, close the filestream
fileStream.close();
```

EDIT: changed filemode from READ to WRITE. READ does not create the file ofcourse :)

Comment: Nothing created, sorry. 
>I changed 'applicationStorageDirectory' to 'applicationDirectory'.     >Create new air app, save it, Ctrl-Enter it (for testing), and error comes up :  
>SecurityError: fileWriteResource
 at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()
 at CreateTXTfile_AIR_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[CreateTXTfile_AIR_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:18]
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
 at runtime::AppRunner/run()
 at ADLAppEntry/run()
 at global/runtime::ADLEntry()

Comment: You cannot write to applicationDirectory without administrator privileges. Change it back to applicationStorageDirectory to see if the script works

Comment: Ok, I changed it back to applicationStorageDirectory. No error, but still doesn't work. No file created. :(

Comment: **//create a reference to the file in the applicationStorage Directory**  
Does it means that file already exist ?

Comment: What FileMode did you use? And where do you look if the file is created? applicationStorageDirectory refers to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\APP_ID\Local Store

Comment: no, it does not mean the file exists, it just resolves a path to the file, even if it doesnt exist. You can check if the file exists with 

var fileToCreate:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
fileToCreate          = fileToCreate.resolvePath("myfile.txt");
trace(fileToCreate.exists());

Comment: Check out the links to the adobe-documentation, its pretty well explained there:

The File class includes static properties that let you reference commonly used directory locations. These static properties include:

File.applicationStorageDirectory—a storage directory unique to each installed AIR application
File.applicationDirectory—the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)
File.desktopDirectory—the user's desktop directory
File.documentsDirectory—the user's documents directory
File.userDirectory—the user directory

Comment: Adobe said : "A File object represents a path to a file or directory. This can be an existing file or directory, **or it can be one that does not yet exist**; for instance, it can represent the path to a file or directory that you plan to create. "  _You're right, Marijn._

Comment: I was trying using your code **trace(fileToCreate.exists());** but it raise an error like this _1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method exists through a reference with static type flash.filesystem:File._

Comment: What is the meaning of '**AIR application**'? Is it the **swf** that I created after I press the CTRL-ENTER or when I select publish? In my assumption 'application' always the 'exe'

Comment: Sorry, the exists isn't a function, but a property. Use trace(fileToCreate.exists); (see here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#exists)

Publish or CTRL + Enter doens't make any difference. The file should be created in the appData directory: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\APP_ID\Local Store

Check that folder if the file was created.

Comment: No files found ! I try search using Windows standard searching. Is it (this script) works on your pc?

Comment: Yes this works on my pc, and i'm pretty confident it does on your pc aswell. 

Don't use search. Just browse to the location i mentioned, or create a file at another, easy to find and WRITABLE location